# shared_ptr with dynamic allocated memory and with mmap-ed memory

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, mmap

For my project I am using `shared_ptr` with dynamically allocated `struct`.

At different point I am accessing same `struct`, but on mmap-ed memory.

Is there some trick I can use with `shared_ptr`, so not to duplicate existing code? For example a custom deleter that actually does not delete?

I realize this will be still risky, but it will be done for very short period of time - inside function body and I do not want to copy the whole struct, just to run some simple function over it.

Comment: What's the risk here exactly?

Comment: risk is to keep pointer to mmap after unmap

Comment: So if you duplicate existing code, will the risk go away?

Comment: no. risk have nothing to do with code duplication

Comment: If you control the mapped memory, you can use the custom deleter to block it from unmapping.

Comment: Another risk is calling `delete` on mmap-ed memory?

Comment: well probably I did not explained it well. since struct is not allocated on the heap, it can not be `delete`. No matter if it is on mmap or not. Suppose this struct is pass to function, that copy the shared_ptr, pass to another function and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, for MMAP related case, I did custom deleter that delete nothing.

```
static void null_deleter(void *){
    // null_deleter
}

...

void abc(Blob *p){
    mySharedPtr.reset(p, null_deleter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *[aliasing constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/)* of `std::shared_pointer`:

```
std::shared_ptr shm;  // points at mmap'ed region, with munmap deleter
Foo *p; // somewhere within this region

auto shared_p = std::shared_ptr{p, shm};
```

This will increase the reference count of `shm` while `shared_p` is live.

Comment: are you additionally proposing shm deleter to unmap the memory?

Comment: That's probably worth considering, but for this code, it only needs to be pointed at by a `shared_ptr` (so `shm` could have a no-op deleter if you want).  If you do so, you'll need to capture the length argument to do the unmap - something like `shm = std::shared_ptr<void*>(mmap(0, len, ...), [len](void *p) {munmap(p, len);}`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

check out the boost interprocess library which allows creating objects in memory created by mmap() of a file. They have some relocateable pointer, to be able to point to objects inside the same memory arena and map this arena at different locations. What is not supported is relocation of virtual function tables -- they discuss this. But I think this would only apply, if you either have different versions of an executable or the virtual method table is located inside a shared library.